# Filtering on all values and export all rows pertaining to each value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a bit of trouble getting this macro to work properly. Basically what I need it to do is take a column, filter on every single unique string in that column, export it to a new workbook, and save the new workbook as the name of the filtered value in the same directory as the xlsm. It almost works perfectly, with the exception of one thing...

What happens: When a list is completely `UNFILTERED`, it will take the first row of each unique value and copy that row, export and save it. I need it to take all rows containing that value in the passed column.

If I filter the column to only include blanks, then it'll work but it will omit the header and the rows will be hidden in the newly created file.

I'm kind of stumped at this point.

I really appreciate your help!

```
Sub TEST()

    Dim hasHeader As Boolean
    Dim colLetter As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim d As Range
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim lastValue As String

    SavePath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    ' CHANGE IF NEEDED'
    hasHeader = True
    ' CHANGE IF NEEDED'
    ' CHANGE IF NEEDED'
    colLetter = "D"
    ' CHANGE IF NEEDED'

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(colLetter & ":" & colLetter), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Sort
        .SetRange Cells

        If hasHeader Then
            .Header = xlYes
        Else
            .Header = xlNo
        End If

        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply

    End With

    For Each d In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(colLetter & ":" & colLetter)

        If d.value = "" Then Exit For

        If d.Row = 1 And hasHeader = False Then

        Else
            If lastValue <> d.value Then

                If Not (wb Is Nothing) Then
                    wb.SaveAs SavePath & "\" & lastValue & ".xlsx"
                    wb.Close
                End If

                lastValue = d.value
                currentRow = 1
                Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
            End If

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(d.Row & ":" & d.Row).Copy
            wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Select
            wb.Sheets(1).Paste
        End If
    Next

    If Not (wb Is Nothing) Then
        wb.SaveAs SavePath & "\" & lastValue & ".xlsx"
        wb.Close
    End If

    MsgBox ("Saved to: " & ThisWorkbook.Path)

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be a lot quicker to use AutoFilter. Where are you collating the unique values?

Comment: The approach here was to not collate the unique values and instead iterate through the passed column, find a value, keep going through the column until the value changes, copy, create new WB, paste, repeat.

I will definitely look into AutoFilter

Comment: The way I have done this in the past is to extract a list of unique values using Advanced Filter (there are other ways), loop through that applying AutoFilter on each value, copying the filtered data to a new sheet which you can then copy in a new workbook. I dare say you will find code to do this online. This approach avoids having to loop through every row of data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Would you happen to have an example / snippet of your autofilter code for me to review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I have, so you will have to amend sheet names, paths etc

```
Sub x()

'For each unique entry in data sheet column D copies corresponding filtered data to report sheet
'copies sheet to new workbook and saves it under name of unique item

Dim r As Long, lrow As Long
Dim rng As Range

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With Sheets("data")
    lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets.Add().Name = "temp"
    .Range("D1:D" & lrow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("temp").Range("A1"), Unique:=True
     For Each rng In Sheets("temp").Range("A2", Sheets("temp").Range("A2").End(xlDown))
        Sheets("report").Range("B2") = rng
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=rng
        .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Copy Sheets("report").Range("A5")
        Sheets("report").Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True, Filename:="C:\" & rng & ".xls"
        Sheets("report").Range("A5:H" & Sheets("report").Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row).Clear
    Next rng
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    Sheets("temp").Delete
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

SJR's code works well if you modify it as he/she suggested. Thank you!

As for mine... I made some changes to it, and after some testing, if you filter to include only blanks this will work just fine. It is a little messy but I am sure you can adapt it if needed.

Overall I think SJR's code is great but if you must have something like mine, this makeshift code could work too.

```
Sub TEST()

Dim hasHeader As Boolean
Dim colLetter As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim d As Range
Dim currentRow As Long
Dim lastValue As String
Dim HeaderVal As Variant

SavePath = ThisWorkbook.Path

' CHANGE IF NEEDED'
hasHeader = True
' CHANGE IF NEEDED'
' CHANGE IF NEEDED'
colLetter = "D"
' CHANGE IF NEEDED'



 'Store the header in a variant for later use
If hasHeader = True Then
HeaderVal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Rows("1:1")
End If


ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(colLetter & ":" & colLetter), _
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Sort
    .SetRange Cells

    If hasHeader Then
        .Header = xlYes
    Else
        .Header = xlNo
    End If

    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply

End With

For Each d In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(colLetter & ":" & colLetter)

    If d.Value = "" Then Exit For

    If d.Row = 1 And hasHeader = False Then

    Else
        If lastValue <> d.Value Then

            If Not (wb Is Nothing) Then
                wb.SaveAs SavePath & "\" & lastValue & ".xlsx"

                 'Unhide all cells
       ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
       ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
       'insert new row
       Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
       'Set the row equal to headerval from the beginning
       Rows(1).Select
       Rows(1).Value = HeaderVal


                wb.Close
            End If

            lastValue = d.Value
            currentRow = 1
            Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
        End If

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(d.Row & ":" & d.Row).Copy
        wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Select
        wb.Sheets(1).Paste
    End If
Next

If Not (wb Is Nothing) Then
    wb.SaveAs SavePath & "\" & lastValue & ".xlsx"


    wb.Close
End If

MsgBox ("Saved to: " & ThisWorkbook.Path)

End Sub
```